# searching json ouput in python

Tags: python, json

So I'm attempting to learn how to search the output of trakt.tv's api and return only the information for a certain show. The json ouput is as follows

```
[
  {
      "title": "NCIS",
      "year" : 2003,
      "url": "blah"
    },
   {   
       "title": "Jeffersons",
       "year" : 1902,
       "url": "notreally"
     }
]
```

:edited code for correct formatting.

I'm trying to find only the information for the title NCIS. and I've run into a problem getting the information. Possibly because everything i've seen deals with json.dump or json.loads and i'm trying to do this with `data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))`

I basically only want to display show:0 if title matches NCIS. I'm just not sure how.

Comment: What [trakt.tv API method](http://trakt.tv/api-docs) are you using?

Comment: Then your example JSON misrepresents the actual output, as far as [the documentation for search/shows](http://trakt.tv/api-docs/search-shows) is concerned.

Comment: then i probably mistyped it seeing as i have 15 windows open

Answer (score 4):

The [`/search/shows` API method](http://trakt.tv/api-docs/search-shows) returns a list of shows (each a mapping) that match your search.

You can simply loop over these and match the specific title:

```
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

for show in data:
    if show['title'] == 'NCIS':
        # matching show
```

or you could use a generator expression to get one matching show:

```
try:
    ncis_show = next(show for show in data if show['title'] == 'NCIS')
except StopIteration:
    ncis_show = None  # not found
```

Comment: Using next() is very elegant imo